# How to use BindingResult Thymeleaf validation?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a bit issue related to binding result thymeleaf validation.
on form submit with empty string binding result is not validate.
please you help me to check and advise me what should I fix this issue.
Thank!!

1. UserDTO

```
@Entity
public class UserDTO {
   @Id
   @NotEmpty(message = "First Name is required!!")
   private String firstName;
   @NotEmpty(message = "Last Name is required!!")
   private String lastName;
   @NotEmpty(message = "Username is required!!")
   private String username;
   @NotEmpty(message = "Password is required!!")
   private String password;
   @NotEmpty(message = "Confirm password is required!!")
   private String confirmPassword;
   @NotEmpty(message = "Role is required!!")
   private String authentication;

   //setter getter
```

2. Controller

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/addUser")
   public String saveUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userDTO") UserDTO userDTO, BindingResult 
   bindingResult, ModelMap model) {
       if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
           return "createUser";
       }

       User userDb = userRepo.findUserByUsername(userDTO.getUsername());
       if (userDb != null) {
           throw new RuntimeException("User already exist.");
```

3. CreateUser.html

```
<form th:action="@{/addUser}" class="form-horizontal"
      novalidate="novalidate" th:object="${userDTO}" method="post">
      <div class="form-body">
           <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Fist Name
                <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" th:value="null"
                         data-required="1" class="form-control">
                         <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}">First Name is required!</span>
                    </div>
              </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label col-md-3">Last Name
                  <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
          </label>
         <div class="col-md-4">
               <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"
                   data-required="1" class="form-control">
             <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}" th:errors="*{lastName}">Last Name is required!</span>
             </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: what is your problem? you provide all values but hasErrors() returns true or you provide empty values and hasErrors() returns false?

Comment: @a4dev92 I try to test with negative mean that I request with empty value from user input but . Binding result should be has errors but it always return "FALSE"